# deployment YML using Github Actions to shares Siteground server

Tags: github-actions

I have a `yml` file and using GitHub actions. I am moving up code that is using React / Typescript. the `npm` build is running fine. However, when I get to the deployment stage it seems to be failing. GitHub actions shows this error:

Uploading files

```
/usr/bin/git ftp push --force --auto-init --verbose --syncroot=./ --user=*** --passwd=***  ***
  Wed Feb 14 01:28:55 UTC 2024: git-ftp version 1.6.0 running on Linux 13d0e8be6ce6 6.2.0-1019-azure #19~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 10 22:57:03 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  Wed Feb 14 01:28:55 UTC 2024: Forced mode enabled.
  Wed Feb 14 01:28:55 UTC 2024: Auto init if needed.
  Wed Feb 14 01:28:55 UTC 2024: Using syncroot ./ if exists.
  Wed Feb 14 01:28:55 UTC 2024: Syncroot is './'.
  Wed Feb 14 01:28:55 UTC 2024: fatal: Not a Git project? Exiting...
Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 8
✅ Deploy Complete
```

Here is the `YML` section:

```yaml
# Pipeline triggered when pushing to the "test" branch
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test

jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install --force
      
      - name: Build the site
        run: npm run build --force
        
        env:
          FTP_SERVER: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER_FRONT }}
          FTP_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME_FRONT }}
          FTP_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD_FRONT }}
      
      - name: Deploy to SiteGround via FTP
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1
        with:
          ftp-server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER_FRONT }}
          ftp-username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME_FRONT }}
          ftp-password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD_FRONT }}
          local-dir: ./
```

I was expecting the deploy to be successful and move up my most recent changes. Instead it seems as though nothing is moving up to my siteground server.

Comment: Please show your complete workflow.

Comment: I have added the full YML to the post. Thank you

Comment: Try: `uses: actions/checkout@v4` and `uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.3`

Comment: Check these [similar reported issues](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ASamKirkland%2FFTP-Deploy-Action+%22Not+a+Git+project%22&type=issues).

Comment: Upgrading to uses: actions/checkout@v4 and uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.3 did the trick. Thank you